# Заполнение ListView через массив

Tags: java, android, listview

У меня есть android приложение, которое в цикле из `json` строки берёт необходимые данные и запихивает их в переменную. После этого нужно заполнить `ListView` массивом из этих переменных. Массив я заполняю в этом же цикле, и после его завершения создаю адаптер и присваиваю его моему `ListView`. Но ничего не выходит...  Вот код:

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(jj);
String[] val = new String[20]; //необходимый мне массив
int i;

//Сам цикл:
for (i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {

    JSONObject obj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

    String lesson = obj.getString("lesson");
    String task = obj.getString("task");

    //Вот моя переменная "data"
    String data = lesson + ": " + task;
    //Которую я запихиваю в массив в соответствии с порядком (счетчик i)
    val[i] = data;
}

//И дальше делаем адаптер и в listView его:
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mass);
lv.setAdapter(adapter); //lv - listView
```

`ListView` инициализировал, проверял - всё нормально...
Помогите пожалуйста кто чем может..

Comment: ну понятно дело не выходит. Вы свой массив то передайте в list. А то у вас в коде массив `val` а в lv вы передаете `mass`

Comment: @ArchDemon, Фу, простите. Нет-нет, там опечатка. Там val передаётся..

Comment: А чем в данном случае является `this`?

Comment: Под "ничего не выходит" вы что подразумеваете? Лист вью ничего не отображает? Отображает что то не то? Выразитесь конкретнее. И я так понимаю описание массива, цикл и передача массива в адаптер у вас в разных методах? В каких?